# Pip does not acknowledge Cython

Tags: python, pip, pytables

I just installed pip and Python via home-brew on a fresh Mac OS installation.

First of all, my pip is not installing dependencies at all - which forces me to re-run 'pip install tables' 3 times and every time it will tell me a dependency and I will install that and then rerun it again. Is this expected behavior?

Second, it does not accept the installation of Cython that it installed itself moments ago:

```
$ pip show cython
---
Name: Cython
Version: 0.21
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires:
```

But

```
$ pip install tables
Downloading/unpacking tables
  Downloading tables-3.1.1.tar.gz (6.7MB): 6.7MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/r_/9cc9_ldj7g35cqnfql52hqt80000gn/T/pip_build_excuvator/tables/setup.py) egg_info for package tables
    * Using Python 2.7.8 (default, Aug 24 2014, 21:26:19)
    * Found numpy 1.9.0 package installed.
    * Found numexpr 2.4 package installed.
    .. ERROR:: You need Cython 0.13 or greater to compile PyTables!
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    * Using Python 2.7.8 (default, Aug 24 2014, 21:26:19)

* Found numpy 1.9.0 package installed.

* Found numexpr 2.4 package installed.

.. ERROR:: You need Cython 0.13 or greater to compile PyTables!
```

Comment: I had the same problem on my Ubuntu 14.04.1 box the other day. It seems to be a bug in Cython that has been fixed but not made it in a release yet: https://github.com/cython/cython/commit/43342ab90704f5f850733544288485048160003d You can edit the PyTables source to get the proper variable from Cython

Comment: I'm not an expert on Pip, could you explain the procedure in a bit more detail?

Comment: Ha! I tricked it. I installed an older version of Cython, then tables, then updated Cython. >)

Comment: Glad you fixed it, because I cannot figure out what I did to work around this! :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Upgrading Cython from the upstream Git repo will resolve the problem.

```
 pip install --upgrade git+git://github.com/cython/cython@master
```

Comment: Install pytables from git worked for me: pip install git+https://github.com/PyTables/PyTables