# PyTables does not seem to acknowledge hdf5

Tags: pip, pytables, h5py

I have a similar issue to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069080/pip-does-not-acknowledge-cython)  PyTables does not seem to acknowledge hdf5 though it is evidently installed. Here is a slightly abbreviated error message from pip.

(And I'm going to ramble a bit more just because I get the annoying "this is mostly code" warning.)

```
pip install --upgrade h5py
Requirement already up-to-date: h5py in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...
$ pip install --upgrade tables
Downloading/unpacking tables
  Downloading tables-3.1.1.tar.gz (6.7MB): 6.7MB downloaded

    ld: library not found for -lhdf5
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    * Using Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05)
    * Found numpy 1.9.0 package installed.
    * Found numexpr 2.4 package installed.
    * Found Cython 0.21 package installed.
    ld: library not found for -lhdf5
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    .. ERROR:: Could not find a local HDF5 installation.
       You may need to explicitly state where your local HDF5 headers and
       library can be found by setting the ``HDF5_DIR`` environment
       variable or by using the ``--hdf5`` command-line option.
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    /var/folders/0w/y_9w4kq53pqfgrc72bb7cml40000gn/T/H5closekvR8zE.c:1:1: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]

ld: library not found for -lhdf5

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

* Using Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05)

* Found numpy 1.9.0 package installed.

* Found numexpr 2.4 package installed.

* Found Cython 0.21 package installed.

ld: library not found for -lhdf5

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

.. ERROR:: Could not find a local HDF5 installation.

   You may need to explicitly state where your local HDF5 headers and

   library can be found by setting the ``HDF5_DIR`` environment

   variable or by using the ``--hdf5`` command-line option.
```

Comment: I think your problem may be due to the fact that h5py does not need the hdf5 header files, while pytables does. To install them (on debian based systems): sudo apt-get install hdf5-dev